# Error ORA-01858. Java throwing an error message in a different language

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to run an UPDATE command in SQL developer, and it was throwing an error with a spanish description: ORA-01858 .Apparently, since my SQL developer was not in English, that was the reason.. So I changed the language of my sql developer by adding the line "AddVMOption -Duser.language=en to the conf file and restarted it. Now the update command was working fine in sql developer

Now, I am trying to run that same command in Java (connected eclipse to SQL developer ). I have other commands in Java that run fine. My Eclipse is in English already however I am, in Eclipse, getting the exact same error I was getting yesterday (ORA-01858) with that "update" command. and the error is being thrown in Spanish

I already restarted Eclipse(thought maybe it hadn't catched up to the fact that my sql developer is in English now) but still same error in Eclipse.

```
Error Msg = ORA-01858: se ha encontrado un carácter no numérico donde se esperaba uno numérico
```

why is the error being thrown in Spanish even though both my eclipse and my sql developer are in English ?

Comment: make sure your NLS session settings are also set to english/american/whatever

Comment: @thatjeffsmith what is NLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same you did for SQL developer: Add VM option `-Duser.language=en`

In Eclipse, you do that in the [Run Configuration](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm).

[image: Run Configuration screenshot]

Comment: do I have to do that even though my eclipse is already in English?

Comment: The Eclipse language has nothing to do with how JVM sets the default language when you run a Java program.

Comment: is there a way to permanently set it to English? rather than always having to pass those arguments. Thanks btw, your approach solved my problem

Comment: Change the regional settings in your OS to be English, because that's where the default that Java uses comes from.